# Is there a way to replace a magic superblock?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, disk, mdadm, disk-management

Following instructions from the Internet (Without doing research first) I have blanked out the superblock on the incorrect RAID disk.  Using this command;

> sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd

Now when I try to assemble the array I get this error;

> mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdd (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)

Is there any way to get that superblock back? the data appears to be there still, and even degraded, I would love to get this back in some form... Sadly backups of a 14 TB array are not easy, and the last one is years old :(

edit: This is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and here is the original array build

> ```
>     Version : 1.2   Creation Time : Sun Feb 22 12:11:32 2015
>  Raid Level : raid5
>  Array Size : 13673680384 (13040.24 GiB 14001.85 GB)   Used Dev Size : 1953382912 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)    Raid Devices : 8   Total
> ```
>
> Devices : 8
> Persistence : Superblock is persistent
>
> ```
> Update Time : Sun Feb 22 12:16:32 2015
>       State : clean, degraded, recovering   Active Devices : 7 Working Devices : 8  Failed Devices : 0   Spare Devices : 1
>
>      Layout : left-symmetric
>  Chunk Size : 512K
> ```
>
> Rebuild Status : 0% complete
>
> ```
>        Name : guppy:0  (local to host guppy)
>        UUID : 638274dd:1e546e4f:2d6c6d10:ee3ca38d
>      Events : 12
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>    0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
>    1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
>    2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
>    3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
>    4       8       80        4      active sync   /dev/sdf
>    5       8       96        5      active sync   /dev/sdg
>    6       8      112        6      active sync   /dev/sdh
>    8       8      128        7      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdi
> ```

Comment: Is there a version of Ubuntu being used?

Comment: You can try the answers from this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643923/mdadm-does-not-find-the-superblock-during-the-assemble-operation

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't have any options for this situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the assistance, but I wasn't able to get the array back with the data.  I ended up having to replace one of the physically bad drives, and just couldn't get anything to recover.  I can see the data is still on the disk using TestDisk utility, however I can't recover any partitions, so I will need to rebuild.
I learned a lot...